# Retorno Dados Excel VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, microsoft

Estou com um problema para retornar os dados do excel para um DataGridView... estou utilizando os comandos abaixo

```
Dim connectionStringExcel As String = "Driver={0};DriverId=790;
Dbq={1};DefaultDir={2};Extended Properties=""HDR=yes"";"

Dim driverExcel As String = "{Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)}"
        conn = New OdbcConnection(String.Format(connectionStringExcel, driverExcel, odb.FileName, Path.GetDirectoryName(odb.FileName)))
cmd = New OdbcCommand("select * from [Plan1$]", conn)
da = New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
dt = New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
```

O problema é que quando uma coluna tem muitos valores numéricos ele considera como uma coluna numérica e não retorna dados alfanuméricos, gostaria de saber como definir o tipo de dado da consulta.

Comment: Já passei por isso, É só alterar o **TIPO** da coluna no EXCEL.

Comment: A Coluna já estava na Categoria Geral, alterei na formatação de célula para Texto porem mesmo assim não retornou os dados.

Comment: Da um SALVAR COMO e muda o nome.

Comment: Realizei o processo e mesmo assim não resolveu. 
obs. Estou utilizando Office 2013.

Comment: Talvez o @Marcelo Bonifazio possa te ajudar.